# How do I create a method that takes into account annual salary raise, annual interest rate and number of months to calculate the balance in the bank?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, bank

I am having a bit of trouble creating a method that calculates the bank balance at the end of n months.

Given the 3 variables =

1. monthlySalary: what the employee earns at the start of every month
2. monthlyInterest: the monthly interest rate
3. adjustedRaise: the annual raise at the start of every new year on the employee's salary e.g. if an employee earns 24K a month, into the 13th month (aka 2nd year), if he gets a raise of 10%, the new monthly salary will be 24K*1.1
4. base: a duplicate if the monthly salary to update the annual raise every year.

-

```
public double compute(int months){
    double monthlySalary = employee.getSalary();
    double base = employee.getSalary();
    double monthlyInterest = (bankName.getInterestRate())/12;
    double adjustedRaise = s.adjust(annualRaise);

    if (months <= 12){
      for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++){
        monthlySalary = monthlySalary*monthlyInterest+monthlySalary;
      }
      return monthlySalary;
    }
    else{
      int cycle = months/12;

      while (cycle >0){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
          monthlySalary = monthlySalary*monthlyInterest+monthlySalary;
        }
        cycle--;
        months = months - 12; //remainder of months
        base = base*(1+adjustedRaise/100); //new starting salary
```

While I am able to create the method when the if condition is 12 months or less, I am unsure how to carry on with the else method when n months is more than 12, can I get some help with how I can proceed with this method?

Comment: When is the salary paid (added to account)? When and how often is the interest capitalized?

Comment: On a side note. Consider using “Currency and Money” API (JSR-354) introduced in JDK 8. It'll handle a lot of precision problems for you.

Comment: The salary is paid at the start of every month, and the interest is capitalised monthly! @JoakimDanielson